# Dynamic Range - Modifiying Range by referencing other cell values

Tags: excel

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER('[IdentiTi Implant Forecast.xlsx]IDCV'!$B$11:$B$80,('[IdentiTi Implant Forecast.xlsx]IDCV'!$B$11:$B$80<>"")))
```

Is there a way that I could have this formula reference a cell to get and modify the ranges?

So for example I have a cell that list `95`, I want the formula to basically reference that cell and go from the above formula to

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER('[IdentiTi Implant Forecast.xlsx]IDCV'!$B$11:$B$95,('[IdentiTi Implant Forecast.xlsx]IDCV'!$B$11:$B$95<>"")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use INDEX:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER('[IdentiTi Implant Forecast.xlsx]IDCV'!$B$11:INDEX('[IdentiTi Implant Forecast.xlsx]IDCV'!$B:$B,$A$1),($B$11:INDEX('[IdentiTi Implant Forecast.xlsx]IDCV'!$B:$B,$A$1)<>"")))
```

Where `$A$1` is the cell in which you place the `95`